# bash, find all strings in a var

Tags: bash, var, cut

I'm Making a script to get DAR information out of video file.
to do that, I'm using this script with success

```
DAR=$(ffmpeg -i "$DOSSIER/$OLD_NAME.$EXTENSION" -hide_banner 2>&1 | grep -i -oP "DAR [0-9]+:[0-9]+")
# if DAR not exist set it to 1
if [ -z "$DAR" ];
    then 
        DAR="DAR 1:1"
fi
X_DAR=$(echo "${DAR:4}" | cut -d: -f1)
Y_DAR=$(echo "${DAR:4}" | cut -d: -f2)
```

My main problem is that sometimes, videos have multiple DAR so my output looks like

```
echo $DAR
DAR 16:9 DAR 5:4 DAR 234:211
```

from there, I would need the biggest number of all operations available behind the DAR. and there could be 2 DAR available or 10.

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Which number has to be the biggest? The one left from the ``:`` or right?

Comment: the biggest one could be any of the DAR. the ":" means divided (/). so 16:9=1,77777777 5:4=1,25 and 234:211=1,10900474 here, the biggest numbre is 16:9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort it by the number left to `:` then do this:

```
for((n=1;n<$(echo $DAR | wc -w)+1;n+=2)); do echo $DAR | cut -d' ' -f$n,$(($n + 1)); done | sort -k2 --numeric-sort -r | head -n1
```

Or if you want to sort it by the number right to `:` then do this:

```
for((n=1;n<$(echo $DAR | wc -w)+1;n+=2)); do echo $DAR | cut -d' ' -f$n,$(($n + 1)); done | sort -t: -k2 --numeric-sort -r | head -n1
```

Output:

```
DAR 234:211
```

EDIT:

Now this first divides the two numbers and then sorts them by the result.

```
for((n=1;n<$(echo $DAR | sed "s/ /\n/g" | wc -l)+1;n+=2)); do echo $DAR | cut -d' ' -f$n,$(($n + 1)); done | awk -F'[ :]' '{printf "%s %s:%s;%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$2/$3}' | sort -t';' -k2 --numeric-sort | tail -n1 | cut -d';' -f1
```

Comment: don't you think that leaving `$DAR` unquoted is a mistake? `echo "$DAR" | sort -t" " -k2n| tail -n1` should be enough ;-)?

Comment: the idea is not bad, I could make the division then numeric-sort. I'll see what I can find about that

Comment: @Nexius2 I extended the answer by a possible way to do the division before sorting.